# Retornar valores do module.exports pelo return

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Tenho o seguinte código que os dados estão retornando certinho pelo `console.log()`

```
var request = require("request");
var myJSON = require("JSON");

function resultado(url, callback) {
    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        callback(null, body);
    });
}


module.exports.cfg = resultado('http://localhost/conf/site', function(err, body) {
    console.log(body)
    return body
});
```

quando eu do require nesse arquivo em outro

```
var conf = require('./config/config')
console.log(conf.cfg);
```

ele retorna **undefined**

alguém ai poderia me ajudar como recuperar esses valores é pode usar eles ? igual retorna no `console.log(body)` ?

ou se existe algum pacote que já faça isso ?

Answer (score 1):

`module.exports` não é um objeto só por si. Se fizeres `module.exports = 'foo';` ele vai exportar uma string. Ou seja tens de fazer explicitamente `= {};`.

Porem há outro problema, é que essa função é assincrona, assim o melhor é exportar a função. A minha sugestão é:

```
module.exports = resultado;
```

e depois usar assim:

```
var conf = require('./config/config');
cfg('http://localhost/conf/site', (err, body){
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(body);
    // e aqui dentro podes continuar o código com o body disponível
});
```